# GridPane stay centered while window is resized

Tags: javafx, gridpane

Currently my gridpane stays centred on the X axis while the window is resized, how can I get it to stay centred on the Y axis as well?

I have this in a tab in a TabPane:

```
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(20);
    grid.setVgap(20);

    this.setContent(grid);
```

Comment: You have to add some kind of code so that we can see what you are doing and how you are doing it.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I've added the code

Comment: If you want a specific answer you should add the complete code for the view.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5af5a4b9630f2e92920b354bcec62b5c) is the full view, still haven't been able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is `VBox.setVgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication65 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(mb, tabPane);


        //StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        CreateProfilePane cp = new CreateProfilePane();
        tabPane.getTabs().add(cp);
        VBox.setVgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);



        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: my StackPane is in a Tab so the grid still isn't centralised when the window is resized. Is there any way around it? @SedrickJefferson

Comment: please see [this](https://gyazo.com/642302a0d1ea63b779f8c638708393d3) screenshot, the StackPane is filled in green.

Comment: looks like you need vgow = Always on stackpane;

Comment: I forgot to mention that the TabPane is in a VBox, so it still doesn't work. Thanks for your help, sorry for being retarded

Comment: Why is it in a VBox?

Comment: I have a MenuBar and then a TabPane in the VBox